# ASP.NET user can still log in if account is inactive or deleted from database

Tags: asp.net

I have a website using ASP.net ... I use the ASP.net website administration tool accessed from Visual Web Developer to add/modify user access to the site. I've noticed that if the user has checked the "remember me" box to auto log in, then disabling or deleting the account has no effect until the cookie is removed. Why is this? Can there be some type of logic put in the code behind that will deny access or redirect them to an error message for disabled or deleted accounts?

This is currently what I have in my code behind...

```
Protected Sub Page_Init(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Init

    If User.Identity.IsAuthenticated Then
        Response.Redirect("~/homepage")
    End If

End Sub
```

Also this is below the Page_Init section...

```
Protected Sub LoginUser_LoginError(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles LoginUser.LoginError

    LoginUser.FailureText = "Invalid Username or Password - Please Try Again"

    Dim usrInfo As MembershipUser = Membership.GetUser(LoginUser.UserName)

    If usrInfo IsNot Nothing Then
        If usrInfo.IsLockedOut Then
            LoginUser.FailureText = "Your account has been locked - Contact the system administrator"
        ElseIf Not usrInfo.IsApproved Then
            LoginUser.FailureText = "Your account is disabled - Contact the system administrator"
        End If
    End If

End Sub
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Besides checking if user `IsAuthentricated`, how about also checking if user account is still active.

Comment: How would I check to see if the user is active or not?

Comment: It has a `GetUser` method. If user doesn't exist anymore, the method returns null. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/40w5063z.aspx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you've noticed, `IsAuthenticated` will return true for a user even after they've been removed. This is because the call only checks the contents of the authentication cookie, which still resides on their system.

One solution to this is to enable role-based security for the site. Using roles means that you can protect sections of your site from certain categories of users, e.g. making the administration pages visible only to a subset of accounts.

This role information is saved in the backing store, not the cookie, so it has to be properly checked every time. It's also deleted when the user is deleted, so your protected pages will be inaccessible to the user as soon as they're removed.

You should still be able to manage all this through the web-based tools, too.

More here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5k850zwb.aspx

Answer (score 1):

The solution is simple: in global.asax.cs, implement session_start and sign out the user if it does not exist in the database:

```
    protected void Session_Start()
    {
        if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated
            && // !(user exists in the database)
            )
        {
            // Remove this forms-authentication cookie, and redirect to sign in without processing this request any further.
            FormsAuthentication.SignOut();
            FormsAuthentication.RedirectToLoginPage();
       }
    }
```

Comment: This will only happen when the user reopens the browser... :(